# Is there a limit to the number of web properties one can create in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a client account in Google Analytics. The client operates about 30 sites and I want to create a web property for each site under the umbrella central account.

Looks like I cannot add more than 20 web properties under one central account.

Can someone confirm if there's a limit to the amount of web properties you can create under one account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a limit of 50 *web properties* per account as specified under:

[Analytics Help -> Analytics accounts -> Analytics accounts organization](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1102152?hl=en#analytics_accounts)

> If you are using Analytics to track a single website, account
>   organization is simple: you will have one account for your website.
>   For setting up Analytics accounts to manage multiple websites, keep in
>   mind the following:
>
> Each Analytics account can have up to 50 properties and each property
>   can have up to 25 views.

Existing properties can be updated and reused however.

As also indicated there:

> Contact your support representative if you need more properties or
>   views.

Comment: Oh... would the support representative allow for more properties for a monthly fee?

Comment: It appears so. You can chat with a support rep or email them to ask [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/?hl=en#topic=1726911) (under Contact Us) .

Answer (score 1):

According to their [support forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/analytics/yJe258PiwAI):

> There are a maximum of 50 profiles per Analytics Account, and a limit of 25 Analytics Accounts per email address.